# "NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from thridparty.mailserver: 554 5.7.1 Relay access denied"

Tags: postfix

I have recently upgraded my production server (Ubuntu 15 to Ubuntu 16.04.1).

Before the upgrade, I've follow [this tutorial](https://easyengine.io/tutorials/mail/server/postfix-dovecot-ubuntu/) for configuring Dovecot/Postfix and Vimbadmin.

Now, i can send succefully email but it's not possible to receive any e-mail. I have this error message from the mail.log :

```
mail postfix/smtpd[10751]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from col004-omc2s1.hotmail.com[xxxx]: 554 5.7.1 <MON@EMAIL.COM>: Relay access denied; from=<EXPEDITEUR@hotmail.com> to=<MON@EMAIL.COM> proto=ESMTP helo=<COL004-OMC2S1.hotmail.com>
```

Sep 17 21:00:38

Here is my postfix conf :

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
mydestination = localhost
myhostname = mail.domain.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
non_smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12301
policy-spf_time_limit = 3600s
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.domain.com/chain.pem
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_error_sleep_time = 2s
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 20
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:12301
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_non_fqdn_recipient reject_unknown_recipient_domain permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination smtpd_relay_restriction check_policy_service unix:private/policy-spf check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 10
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.domain.com/cert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.domain.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_tls_wrappermode = no
smtpd_use_tls = yes
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `mydestination = localhost` to include your domain(s).

http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html

> The mydestination parameter specifies what domains this machine will
>   deliver locally, instead of forwarding to another machine. The default
>   is to receive mail for the machine itself. See the VIRTUAL_README file
>   for how to configure Postfix for hosted domains.
>
> You can specify zero or more domain names, "/file/name" patterns
>   and/or "type:table" lookup tables (such as hash:, btree:, nis:, ldap:,
>   or mysql:), separated by whitespace and/or commas. A "/file/name"
>   pattern is replaced by its contents; "type:table" requests that a
>   table lookup is done and merely tests for existence: the lookup result
>   is ignored.
>
> IMPORTANT: If your machine is a mail server for its entire domain, you
>   must list $mydomain as well.
>
> Example 1: default setting.
>
> /etc/postfix/main.cf:
>       mydestination = $myhostname localhost.$mydomain localhost

As for your second problem, you'll have to clarify what you mean and provide more information... best to post a second question.

Comment: Thanks ! i've modified mydestination with `mydestination = $myhostname localhost.$mydomain localhost mail.mydomain.com` and i've checked my log and i've again the same error `NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from`

Comment: @Shinix If your domain is `example.com`, you must include it as such. `mydestination = example.com`. It looks like you didn't do that. The example I quoted wasn't quite right for your situation, it was just showing the default setting for Postfix.

Comment: Oops, thanks i've modified to `mydestination = example.com` but i've a `<contact@domain.com>: unknown user: "contact"`. I think mydestination can be empty ? [info here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18381975/5542131)

Comment: `user unknown` = totally different problem. Post another question please.

Comment: is not working,